# Getting all documents from a property-combo

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

This might be very simple, however I am having a hard time figuring it out:

I have a `List<Tuple<String, String>>` that contains a list of products that I need to search for, and I would like to get all documents of all products that is represented in that list in one request.

`Item1` is the SKU of the product, but because there can be duplicate SKU's, i also have `Item2` which contains which SupplierId it should look for.

My challenge is to build the Query with the MongoDB C# Driver, to get the data out, anyone that can help?

I am using the new 2.3.0 driver version, which doesn't have much exsiting help on this subject.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<StockDoc>("stock");
var result = collection.Find().ToListAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your StockDoc class as:

```
public class StockDoc
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string SupplierId { get; set;}
}
```

I would write a help method that creates filter  for each tuple from the list (it's and filter: `SKU = Item1 && SupplierId == Item2`):

```
public FilterDefinition<StockDoc> BuildFilter(Tuple<String, String> p) 
{
    return Builders<StockDoc>.Filter.And(
                Builders<StockDoc>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.SKU, p.Item1),
                Builders<StockDoc>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.SupplierId, p.Item2) );
}
```

After that you could build an `Or` filter to get items for all tuples from the list:

```
var p = new List<Tuple<String, String>> { 
       Tuple.Create("a", "1"), 
       Tuple.Create("b", "1"), 
       Tuple.Create("d", "2")};

var filter = Builders<StockDoc>.Filter.Or(p.Select(BuildFilter));
```

After that you could get your data with this filter:

```
collection.Find(filter).ToList()
```